# Detect whether bootstrap carousel is going fwd or back

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

How can you tell whether the twitter bootstrap carousel is going fwd or back? I want to be able to do something like:

```
$('#myCarouse').on('slide', function(e) {
  if (fwd?) {do something}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only special info the Carousel plugin appends to the **slide** event object is a `relatedTarget` property which contains the element that is going to be switched to. That can be used to manually calculate where you are about to move in the carousel.

Something along the lines of:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide', function (e) {
  var $active = $(this).find('.item.active')
    , children = $active.parent().children()
    , activePos = children.index($active)
    , nextPos = children.index(e.relatedTarget)
    , diff = nextPos - activePos;

    if (diff === 1 || diff < -1 || diff === 0) {
        console.log('next');
    } else {
        console.log('prev');
    }
});​
```

That `diff === 0` is to handle the strange behavior I saw when on the last slide and moving to the first one.  For some reason, `activePos` and `nextPos` come out equal.  I can't make sense of it; it just *is*.

Here's a demo:

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/yaapK/)

Comment: Seems that the Carousel only sets `relatedTarget` when it's _not_ "looping" (i.e. going to 'next' from the last slide or going to 'prev' from the first slide). I built a solution based on that knowledge, but your answer got me in the right direction.